# Cannot find .pro file in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm new to Qt, learning through a Qt Creator tutorial. I am trying to connect Qt with a MySQL database. To do so, I have to modify a .pro file adding the command QT += core sql

However, once I create a project there is no .pro file in the menu, only the .ccp file.

Program installed: Qt Creator 4.13.0

OS: Windows 10 x64

Steps followed:

1. Choose New Project
2. Choose Qt Console Application
3. Build system: CMake
4. Kits: I have some available; I am using Qt 5.15.1 MSVC2019 64bit

The menu displayed shows a CMakesList.txt file, and the main.ccp source file. However no .pro file is created.

Comment: When you have created the project you have surely selected the option "cmake" as build system generating the CMakeLists.txt instead of the .pro, my recommendation is that you create a project and select qmake as build system.

Comment: CMake does not use .pro files instead it uses CMakeLists.txt files. QMake uses pro files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For new build system you should modify CMakeList.txt file.

Please try to replace

```
target_link_libraries(myapp Qt5::Gui)
```

with

```
target_link_libraries(myapp Qt5::Gui Qt5::Sql)
```